# Using the SUMX function in DAX with multiple filters. Works with string constant but not with variable

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following DAX formula in a table Power BI Desktop:

```
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        DatePQ,
        DatePQ[DatePQ].[Date] <= EARLIER ( DatePQ[DatePQ].[Date] )
            && DatePQ[WH] = DatePQ[WH]
    ),
    DatePQ[QTY]
)
```

As you can see, there are two filters in it. As it is, the function seems to ignore the second filter (for DatePQ[WH]). However, if I write it to equal a string constant:

```
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        DatePQ,
        DatePQ[DatePQ].[Date] <= EARLIER ( DatePQ[DatePQ].[Date] )
            && DatePQ[WH] = "Adams"
    ),
    DatePQ[QTY]
)
```

By using the constant "Adams", the function works properly. However, this value needs to be a variable. For example, if in Excel, with SUMIFS, one could write:

```
SUMIFS(QTY, DatePQ, "="&DatePQ, WH, "="&WH)
```

Where QTY, DatePQ, and WH are the names of the columns.

Thank you for your help as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison `DatePQ[WH] = DatePQ[WH]` is always true since you're comparing the value to itself.
It looks like you are correctly using the [EARLIER](https://dax.guide/earlier/) function for `[DatePQ]` but forgot to do the same for `[WH]`.

Try using EARLIER for both or use variables instead.

```
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        DatePQ,
        DatePQ[DatePQ].[Date] <= EARLIER ( DatePQ[DatePQ].[Date] )
            && DatePQ[WH] = EARLIER ( DatePQ[WH] )
    ),
    DatePQ[QTY]
)
```

or

```
SUMX (
    VAR CurrDate = DatePQ[DatePQ].[Date]
    VAR CurrWH = DatePQ[WH]
    RETURN
        FILTER ( DatePQ, DatePQ[DatePQ].[Date] <= CurrDate && DatePQ[WH] = CurrWH ),
    DatePQ[QTY]
)
```

Comment: Thank you for editing and thank you for your reply! I'm new to BI and figured the EARLIER function had to do only with dates. Much to learn ahead. Thank you again!